# DISTINCT em uma WHERE Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

Preciso retornar as últimas duas compras de cada item da tabela `NOTA_FISCAL_ENTRADA_ITEM`, porém que retorne os valores da coluna `VL_UNITARIO_ENTRADA_EST` diferentes.

Ou seja, se nas últimas duas compras o valor for o mesmo, buscar a próxima compra mais recente com o valor diferente.

No `SELECT` abaixo, consegui retornar somente as duas compras mais recentes.
Como faço para trazer as ultimas duas compras com valores diferentes? Tentei com o `DISTINCT`, mas sem sucesso.

```
SELECT *
from    (
    SELECT CD_ITEM,
    DT_ENTRADA,
    VL_UNITARIO_ENTRADA_EST,
    row_number () over (partition by CD_ITEM order by DT_ENTRADA DESC) ULT_REG
    FROM NOTA_FISCAL_ENTRADA_ITEM
    )
WHERE ULT_REG <= 2
```

Resultado do SELECT atual:

[image: exemplo]

Comment: *" Ou seja, se nas ultimas duas compras o valor for o mesmo, buscar a próxima compra mais recente com o valor diferente"* isso é um pouco difícil de fazer sem ter um exemplo dos dados, mas se usar um `group by` incluindo o campo de valor, e um `order by` para garantir que ordena e pega o próximo valor diferente, deve resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reaproveitando a maioria dos passos dados. A ideia aqui é usar o campo da data para retirar os duplicados, de seguida  ao mesmo tempo que obtemos o ordenação.
Na parte exterior, mantemos só as primeiras N entradas (2).

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    CD_ITEM,
    VL_UNITARIO_ENTRADA_EST,
    DT_ENTRADA,
    row_number () over (partition by CD_ITEM order by DT_ENTRADA DESC) ULT_REG
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      CD_ITEM,
      VL_UNITARIO_ENTRADA_EST,
      MAX(DT_ENTRADA) AS DT_ENTRADA    
    FROM NOTA_FISCAL_ENTRADA_ITEM
    GROUP BY
      CD_ITEM,  
      VL_UNITARIO_ENTRADA_EST
    ORDER BY MAX(DT_ENTRADA) DESC
  ) NOTA_FISCAL_ENTRADA_ITEM_FILTERED
)
WHERE ULT_REG < 3;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @chegancasb !! Funcionou perfeitamente. Era exatamente isso que eu precisava!